# Grails Spring Security SAML plugin "SPSSODescriptor wasn't found"

Tags: grails, spring-security, saml

I've configured the grails saml plugin and its loads the SP metadata file. When I try to access a protected resource on the application I get the following error. I can't seem to find any information about it.

`Metadata for entity testing-app and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor wasn't found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with a typo in the default SP alias. So it was loading the SP metadata file but failing to find the entityDescriptor because the alias lookup was incorrect

Comment: What was done to fix this? How is this a correct answer without giving any indication of a solution?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I tried (since a frustrating percentage of the time this works) was a Google search for **“SPSSODescriptor wasn't found”** (and a few variants, but all with quotes to keep it as a phrase) and only this question came up. It seemed like looking at the code that generated that message would be the quickest path to finding out that's going  on, so I  used GitHub's code search [in the plugin code](https://github.com/fpanwaskar/grails-spring-security-saml) but still no luck. Google searches for **"SPSSODescriptor"** (with quotes to keep it from being split into shorter terms) had lots of results but nothing obviously helpful after a quick scan.

Still looking for code, I tried a relaxed version of that first search: **saml "wasn't found"'** - keeping "wasn't found" together - and that led to discovering this code in the `org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl` class in the spring-security-saml project at GitHub:

```
if (entityDescriptor == null || ,aa,phrase and thatlead to this a/aibg -psroleDescriptor == null) {
    throw new MetadataProviderException("Metadata for entity " + localEntityId + " and role " + localEntityRole + " wasn't found");
}
```

and Bingo! - that is a library used by the plugin.

So it's failing to find a required `<md:SPSSODescriptor>` element (which is contained in an `<md:EntityDescriptor>` descriptor element with namespace `md` and urn `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata`, hence the funky `{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor` part of the error message) for local entity id "testing-app".

If you look at the [sample message flow in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SP_POST_Request.3B_IdP_POST_Response) you'll see that you're not going to get far without the Assertion Consumer Service metadata that's contained in the `<md:SPSSODescriptor>` element

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually found the issue was with a typo in the default SP alias. So it was loading the SP metadata file but failing to find the entityDescriptor because the alias lookup was incorrect